# Spring boot application with Google OAuth2 integration issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I am developing a web application, and using google sign in the application. After adding google sign in the app, it is not starting, it's failing as soon as i run the application. The following error I am getting in console -

```
  APPLICATION FAILED TO START
  ***************************

  Description:

  Binding to target org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.
  security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties@7e00ed0f failed:

  Property: security.oauth2.resource.tokenInfoUri
  Value: null
  Reason: Missing tokenInfoUri and userInfoUri and there is no JWT 
  verifier key

  Action:

  Update your application's configuration
```

My configuration java class is below -

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("name", principal.getName());
        return map;
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(
        OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
      FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
      registration.setFilter(filter);
      registration.setOrder(-100);
      return registration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and().logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
        .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("oauth2")
    public ClientResources google() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(google(), "/goole/login"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
    }


    class ClientResources {

        @NestedConfigurationProperty
        private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

        @NestedConfigurationProperty
        private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

        public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
            return client;
        }

        public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
            return resource;
        }
}
}
```

I guess the resource server not able to read the application.yml file, but I am not sure. Need help to fix the issue. 
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Any luck solving this?

Comment: Looks like there is something missing or wrong in your yml file.